# Function works in debugger, but not in live code

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets to track details about cases. After entering information on the sheet, I paste the URL to the related Doc so it is very easy to open the file from the sheet.

I want to update the description of the Doc file with information from the Sheet. When I paste the URL, I want it to pull the related column information and enter it into the Doc description.

The code is below:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var changedCell= event.source.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
  var column = ss.getRange(changedCell).getColumn();
  if(column == "19"){
    var cellValue =  ss.getRange(changedCell).getValue();
    var id = cellValue.replace("https://drive.google.com/a/mine.net/file/d/","")
                      .replace("https://drive.google.com/open?id=","")
                      .replace("/view?usp=sharing","")
                      .replace("&authuser=0","");
    var row = ss.getRange(changedCell).getRow();
    var desc = Utilities.formatDate(ss.getRange("B"+row).getValue(),"GMT","MM/dd/yyyy")
                   +" "+ss.getRange("C"+row).getValue()
                   +" "+ss.getRange("D"+row).getValue()
                   +" "+ss.getRange("E"+row).getValue();
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    file.setDescription(desc);
  }
}
```

When I run this through debugger, it works perfectly (if I force the `changedCell` and `column` information) and I see the updated description in the related file.

However, when I try to run it from the spreadsheet, I get this error:

`[14-11-23 19:40:31:061 MST] Execution failed: You do not have permission to call getFileById (line 104, file "Code") [0.006 seconds total runtime]`

If I don't have permission, why will it run in debug? And, how do I grant permission? I have full access to both files.

On a related note, is there a better way to extract the id from the url?

**UPDATE**
Here is a screen shot of were I setup the trigger and the called function
[image]
[image]

Even after changing column to a number it still never even hits the alert.

Comment: Are you sure youn don't have another function in the same project called onEdit?  It would prevent the installable onEdit to work...

Comment: The .gs file doesn't have one. Is it possible it is getting one from somewhere else?

Comment: any .gs file bounded to the spreadsheet is always active... so the answer is yes.

Comment: Is there a way for me to see if any other .gs files are bound to this sheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained [in the documentation, simple onEdit triggers have a few restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) in what they can do : they can't call any function that requires explicit authorization.

`DriveApp.getFileById()` is obviously a method that requires authorization.

Just change your function name and create an installable onEdit trigger that calls the function (script editor/menu/ressources/triggers).

As for retrieving the ID from the url you could use the split method to get it :

```
var id = cellValue.split('/d/')[1].split('/')[0];
```

---

### EDIT

As mentioned in the comments, your condition is not correct, column is a number, not a string.

To convince yourself test the following and check the logger.

```
function onEditInstall(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var changedCell= event.source.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
  var column = ss.getRange(changedCell).getColumn();
  Logger.log(typeof(column)+' '+column);// is number
  if(column == 19){
    Browser.msgBox('Luck !')
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I could never get it to run. When I view the triggers I see one with these values: Run="onEditing",  Events="From spreadsheet" "On edit". However, this is never called.

Comment: Have you checked your condition ? I think it is never true because you use "19" as a string but it should be a number... try removing the "" and check again please. Are you sure also about your new function name?  I ran a test myself and it was working.

Comment: I am positive about "19". It works just fine in debugger, and gets to the code inside the if function. I pick the name from the list, so it should be correct. I am not sure what else I am missing.

Comment: Please also read the comments on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107903/use-onedit-trigger-on-a-specific-sheet-within-google-scripts-for-google-sheets. , particularlythe part about function names.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. Unfortunately, I can't find anything stopping it. I guess I will just have to keep doing it manually for now.

Comment: Try a new spreadsheet and implement only my example . Once you have a basic function that works you can develop your script from there... good luck.:-)