# use onedit() trigger on a specific sheet within google scripts for google sheets

Tags: function, if-statement, google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I need to run a script triggered by an onedit() to only one sheet of many.

I have tried the following, but currently I can't get the script to work on just the desired sheet ("Inventory") Im sure this will be very simple for someone that knows:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var range = e.range;
    if(range.getSheetName() == "Inventory") {
        if(range.getValue() == "notify") {
            range.setBackgroundColor('red');
            var productname = range.offset(0,-3).getValue();
            var productinventory = range.offset(0,-2).getValue();
            var message = "Product variant " + productname + " has dropped to " + productinventory;
            var subject = "Low Stock Notification";
            var emailAddress = "email@email.com";
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
            range.offset(0,1).setValue("notified");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try something like this and see if it works:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var range = e.range;
    if (activeSheet.getName() !== "Inventory" || e.value !== "notify") return;
    range.setBackgroundColor('red');
    var productname = range.offset(0, -3).getValue();
    var productinventory = range.offset(0, -2).getValue();
    var message = "Product variant " + productname + " has dropped to " + productinventory;
    var subject = "Low Stock Notification";
    var emailAddress = "email@email.com";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    range.offset(0, 1).setValue("notified");
}
```

Now the script will exit if the active Sheet is not 'Inventory' or the edited value is not 'notify'.

Comment: Although this is a onEdit script, you will have to use an installable trigger (add a trigger > on edit of the spreadsheet) because of the emailing.

Comment: Thanks JPV, unfortunately this didn't work. It doesn't seem to be recognising the sheet. The rest of the function works fine when used on any sheet as I have already installed the onedit. I just cant seem to get it working on just this one! Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Did you check if the name in tab doesn't contain extra spaces ?

Comment: Yeah just checked that, still doesn't seem to work. Gets caught on that first statement still. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I just tested the exact script above and it works fine. please dubbelcheck the tab name and also change the function name to something other than onEdit to avoid internal conflict with the simple onEdit. For example installableOnEdit(e)

Comment: Thanks both of you, renaming the function seems to have got it working!

Comment: Great... it's never a good idea to use onEdit as a function name when it's not a simple onEdit... it tries to run on both ways and one of them inevitably fails...

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, Serge.

Comment: Haven't changed any of the code from when it was working, but for some unknown reason this seems to have stopped working for me. Could this be an update etc? Is it working for you both still? Thanks!

Comment: Remember that Javascript string comparison is case sensitive. Even with ==.

Comment: Hi Guys, any chance you could help with a similar issue on google script:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551543/pull-csv-to-google-sheets-with-basic-authentication

Comment: @JPV Your comment fixed it for me - Apparently normal onEdit run as the user where the actual trigger runs as the developer

Answer (score 9):

I suggest that you try this:

```
range.getSheet().getSheetName() == "Inventory"
```

Comment: While I don’t know whether this worked in 2014, however, today it works. You can simply use `e.range.getSheet().getSheetName()` to get the name of the sheet name where the change occurred.