# Only use script in one sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use this script to set a timestamp when a cell is changed. But it triggers in all sheets, and I only want it to be triggered when I do a change in sheet "XXX"

```js
function onEditDatoMaxboStart() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("XXX"); //change this to the name of your sheet
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 29 ) { 
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+01:00", "dd.MM.yyyy  hh.mm.ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AP' + row.toString()).setValue(time); 
  };
};
```

How do I lock it to only be triggered when I make a change in the sheet "XXX"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use onedit() trigger on a specific sheet within google scripts for google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107903/use-onedit-trigger-on-a-specific-sheet-within-google-scripts-for-google-sheets)

Comment: Please summarise your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot lock onEdit triggers to be ran on specific Sheets. However, within your onEdit function, you can check whether the Sheet that has triggered the action is the one you are targeting. If it is not, you can just return from the function without really executing any action. Your modified function would look as follows (edited only the first two lines):

```js
function onEditDatoMaxboStart(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() !== "XXX") return;
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("XXX"); //change this to the name of your sheet
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 29 ) { 
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+01:00", "dd.MM.yyyy  hh.mm.ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AP' + row.toString()).setValue(time); 
  };
};
```

Also, I suggest you check out [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) on using events objects obtained in trigger functions.