# is there a way to copy a specific tab with all its formatting over to a specific tab of another spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

need some help here.
I have a master google sheet that has several tabs. Most of them contains private information, so i have to import a tab(sourcetab) that is for public view to another spreadsheet so that i can share it on google site.

I have tried importrange but it only copy the values to a destination tab of another spreadsheet.

Problem 1: The source tab has several links, images and formatting that i would need it on the destination.
Problem 2: My management will update the master source tab and would like the destination to be updated automatically as well, with all formatting and links attached.
I understand that google app script might be able to help.

Therefore, will need help to advise on how to duplicate the source tab into a destination tab and get it updated when there is changes in the master tab.

[1][Tried copytab but it only creates a new tab in the source and does not update automatically when there is any editing in the master tab]

```
function copyTab() {
  var ss, sourceSheet, sourceData, sourceDataRange, newSheetTab;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//Get active spreadsheet

  sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sample: Restriction Updates");//Get the source sheet tab
  newSheetTab = ss.insertSheet("newsheet");//Create a new sheet tab

  sourceDataRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();

  sourceDataRange.copyTo(newSheetTab.getRange(1, 1));//Copies the data from a range of 
  //cells to another range of cells. By default both the values and formatting are copied

}
```

[2][Tried to create into the destination but failed]

```
function myFunction() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sourceID');
  var sourceSheet = source.getSheetByName('Sample: Restriction Updates');
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

  var tempSheet = source.getSheetByName('temp');
  var tempRange = tempSheet.getRange('A1');

  var destinationsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('DestinationID');
  var destination = source.getSheetByName('Test');

  sourceRange.copyTo(tempRange);  // paste all formats?, broken references
  tempRange.offset(0, 0, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length)
  .setValues(sourceValues);  // paste all values (over broken refs)

  tempSheet.copyTo(destination);  // now copy temp sheet to another ss
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can I ask why you decided to paste your code as an image instead of text?

Comment: oops. sorry. very new here. let me paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to take the data from one sheet and directly copy it over to another. You also want to have this occur on edits.

You can try using the optional parameter with `.inputSheet()` and specify the template you wish to copy over and see if that works:

```
function myFunction() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sourceID');
  var sourceSheet = source.getSheetByName('Sample: Restriction Updates');
  var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('DestinationID');
  destinationSheet.insertSheet('Test',{template: sourceSheet});
```

This will transfer over values as well as formatting from the sourceSheet over into a new sheet in the destinationSheet.

As for automating this process, you can either use the `.onEdit(e)` trigger to run this process whenever a value is changed in the spreadsheet, or you can set up a trigger to run it on a specific basis. You can use the Apps Script Ui to set a trigger, or you can write the script and run it. Links below:

### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Building Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder)
- [insertSheet(options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetoptions)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. i tried it but it prompt:
1. Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp.
2. Error Exception: Specified sheet must be part of the spreadsheet.
myFunction @ Code.gs:5

Comment: Ahh, well then the .insertSheet() won't work in that case. My apologies; thought it would work cross-sheet. I'm not sure about the first error though.

Comment: no worries. Do feel free to let me know should you have any idea how to do it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `copyTab` function should work, to run it on any change on a sheet, [create an `onEdit` trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107903/use-onedit-trigger-on-a-specific-sheet-within-google-scripts-for-google-sheets):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var editedSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (editedSheet.getName() === "Sample: Restriction Updates")
  {
    copyTab();
  }
}
```

*Note*: if your sheet is edited heavily (few edits per second) you might want to use [Lock service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223774/how-to-understand-lockservice-and-implement-it-correctly) to improve performance of a trigger, so your `copyTab` function won't be running while another instance is not finished:

```
function copyTab() {

  // paste at the beginning of copyTab function:
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  try {
    lock.waitLock(30000); // wait 30 seconds for others' use of the code section and lock to stop and then proceed
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 30 seconds, exiting function call.');
    return;
  }

  // rest of your function code
  ..

  // IMPORTANT release a lock in the end of function
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. yes, copytab but it's only applicable to copying it in the same spreadsheet(SourceID). I would require it to be copied with all formstting to a specific tab(Test) of another spreadsheet (DestinationID) and to be updated on edit. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: I have a smaple spreadsheet for your reference should you need. Thanks a million! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71230434/to-copy-a-specified-tab-from-one-sheet-and-directly-copy-it-over-to-another-dest