# To copy a specified tab from one sheet and directly copy it over to another destination tab of another google sheet and have this occur on edits

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

need some help here. I have a master google sheet(Master Trix) that has several tabs.

Most of them contains private information, so i have to import a specific tab("Numbers") to another specific tab("Test")of another spreadsheet("Destination Source") that is for public view so that i can share it on google site. Edits will be made often on the master trix's tab("Numbers") and has to be reflected upon edit on tab("Test")of another spreadsheet("Destination Source")

I have tried importrange but it only copy the values to a destination tab of another spreadsheet.

Problem 1: The source tab has several links, images and formatting that i would need it on the destination. Problem 2: My management will update the master source tab and would like the destination to be updated automatically as well, with all formatting and links attached. I understand that google app script might be able to help.

I have tried the following:

```
function copytabtodestination() {

 var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];

 var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dKMZhXlCeoaP92kmAlFUq1NgYo38fK_HryCfJ8jBzZ8");

 sheet.copyTo(destination);
}
```

But it creates a new tab that states "copy of Sample: Restriction Updates" . - Not the specific tab("Numbers") that is supposed to be reflected.Is there any way i can get it reflected in the **"test"** tab instead and changes will be updated upon edits?

Master trix: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Uhcq-dztXqZH9hEbF1-Ho7Wr5IQ1yTp3-VDVW5D-bpc/
Destination Source: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dKMZhXlCeoaP92kmAlFUq1NgYo38fK_HryCfJ8jBzZ8/

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

#### Copy Sheet Numbers to another Spreadsheet and Name it Numbers

```
function copyto() {
  const dssid = "1dKMZhXlCeoaP92kmAlFUq1NgYo38fK_HryCfJ8jBzZ8";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sssid = ss.getId();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Numbers');//you can change this to another name if you wish to replace another sheet
  const sshid = sh.getSheetId();
  const options = {"method": "post","headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },"payload":{ "destinationSpreadsheetId": "" + dssid }};
  const url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sssid}/sheets/${sshid}:copyTo`;
  let r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  let title = JSON.parse(r.getContentText()).title;
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dssid);
  let s = dss.getSheetByName(sh.getName());
  if(s)dss.deleteSheet(s);//deletes old numbers if present
  dss.getSheetByName(title).setName(sh.getName());//rename sheet to original sheet name
}
```

Comment: Hi, ive tried your method but it prompt: Error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetId' of null

Comment: and if i want to copy it to another destinationID - would it be possible? cos it prompt: Exception: Request failed for https://sheets.googleapis.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Google Sheets API has not been used in project 253043459260 before or it is disabled. Enable it by ... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: It looks like you have not enabled Google Sheets API

Comment: i copied your script into the apps script but it still prompt: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetId' of null
copyto @ Test.gs:6

Comment: So I guess sh is not defined which means probably that there is not a sheet named Numbers.  There's nothing I can do about that

Comment: I tested it yesterday  and it works.  So if you can't get it running I can't help you.  We have to assume that you at least know how to run a script and have basic debugging skills.

Comment: Sure. Thanks Copper anyways! 